# Magento Extension "Product Advance Option"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have installed advance product options extension under our magento website using ftp, but it is not working, and after installing this extension all tabs under "system > configuration" working close, nothing showing on when i click system > configuartion tab.
So my admin panel is close. various things in admin panel are not working.

I have used magento 1.7.0.2 version.

Please provide me some help as soon as possible.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an install problem, if you can access the `app/etc/modules/MODULE_NAME.xml` and change `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`. Then Log out (if you are logged in) of Magento Admin Area and Re-Log-In. (you may need to clear cache if active still.

If all is back to normal with this in false status, your mod is the issue and you may want to talk to the mod developers.